# Group the json file bot azure conversations into only one

Tags: azure, storage, chatbot

I have a problem with my storage conversation from my bot in Azure Portal . Indeed, with this code in the index.ts file, i can save a conversation.

```
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});


const transcriptStore = new BlobsTranscriptStore("name_of_your_chaine_string_storage_account", "name_of_your_container");
const transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(transcriptStore);
adapter.use(transcriptMiddleware);
```

This is what i get in the Azure Portal :

[Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62EMm.png)

One json file is generated for one action (actions are composed with questions and answers), and i would like to have only one json file with the entire all conversation, do you know how could we do this ?

Thanks for help ! :)